# Touchscreen problem - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in Dell inspiron 13 serie 7000 (7348)

Tags: dell, touchscreen, inspiron

I recently purchased a Dell Inspiron 13 7000 Series 2-in-1 (7348). I would like to install Ubuntu, though still not officially released a version pre-installed on this machine.
Which version of Ubuntu would guarantee the Touchscreen and its rotation of 360° in your opinion? I read the version of ubuntu 12.04 about the dell XPS 13 (the most similar) that allows the touchscreen to function. Do you believe that this version of Ubuntu would be better for my 13 7000 series?
What do you recommend to do?

Thank you, I aspect reply!

Comment: 14.04 LTS is the best choice. If 12.04 worked OK, there is no reason why there are problems with 14.04.

Comment: OK thanks, I install ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I write how it works.

Comment: how dit it go do you still have some problems?

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS installed on Dell inspiron 13 7000 series (7348). Here the results.

It works almost everything. What does not work is:

- The touchpad, the first time I turned on the machine the trackpad worked more or less well: Left click OK, the two-finger scrolling OK, but the right-click did not work; from the second restart the trackpad does not work anymore, the arrow disappears even if the setting is on.
  I read a similar problem here, this can be the solution?
  [Clickpad not working on Dell Inspiron 13 7000, running Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527793/clickpad-not-working-on-dell-inspiron-13-7000-running-ubuntu-14-04)
  I try.
- The touchscreen, it works only in a basic, but it's the only way to move around. Single click OK, it does not work the zoom with two-finger touch and the touch prolonged that served (in windows) to right-click. So it's impossible to use it to take notes with the stylus, much less as a tablet because it does not react to the 360 ° screen rotation.

Can someone please help me?
I wait for answers, Thanks!

[UPDATE]

Touchpad problem SOLVED only doing 'blacklist i2c-hid' solution/workaround described here:

http://trustdarkness.com/wordpress/dell-sputnik-xps-13-touchpad-settings-not-working-in-updated-ubuntumint/

Now touchpad works in all its functions! :)

- Touchscreen problem remains, it works with the basic function of the click. Does anyone know help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can install the orientation program and start it via the terminal command "sudo orientation", or put it in the auto-start list. It needs a root permission. Works the same way as a Windows STMicroelectronics driver: it automatically rotates your view according to the display's position. I believe I've dug it from this post https://github.com/pfps/yoga-laptop