# Touchpad only works after hibernate

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, suspend, hibernate

A couple of days ago, I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell I7352-3111SLV 13 inch touchscreen laptop. Initially, the touchpad worked fine. The first time I suspended, the touchpad stopped working, even with a reboot. I've since reinstalled Ubuntu a couple of times to try to solve the problem without success. The latest time, the touchpad didn't work even with a fresh install.

I have tried several fixes without success including:

[How to install Synaptics on touchpad on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453876/how-to-install-synaptiks-on-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04)

[Synaptic touchpad on laptop not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working)

Since the computer is also not resuming even half the time from Suspend, I enabled hibernate. The odd thing is that coming off a hibernate/resume, the touchpad functions again properly each time. However, when I reboot, the touchpad is non-functioning again until I hibernate.

Even when the touchpad does not work, it is still detected.

```
xinput list
```

Returns

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL06B5:00 06CB:75DB UNKNOWN              id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen Pen                      id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard(2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I'm fairly new to Linux and I would appreciate any suggestions. Maybe there are log files that could be used to compare what is happening with the touchpad on a reboot as opposed to resuming from hibernate?

Comment: Check Touchpad whether it is in enabled mode or not ? @user3221829

Comment: I checked with dconf editor. The touchpad is listed as enabled both when it is working and when it is not working.    <img src="http://www.techpoweredmath.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/screenshot_touchpad_enabled.png">

Comment: Sorry. Having some problems with the markdown for images, but this is a link to the  screenshot:  http://www.techpoweredmath.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/screenshot_touchpad_enabled.png

Comment: Further information that may be helpful. /var/log/dmesg shows the following messages:    [    1.641647] psmouse serio1: synaptics: device claims to have extended capability 0x0c, but I'm not able to read it.    [    1.768585] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Unable to initialize device.        [    2.980093] psmouse serio1: Failed to enable mouse on isa0060/serio1

Comment: Your Configuration is very similar of Dell Inspiron 13 7000 as per specification and Your System Supports only `Windows 8.1\10-64 bit & BIOS` as per DELL Official site. So better try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/527793/clickpad-not-working-on-dell-inspiron-13-7000-running-ubuntu-14-04  It may help you

Comment: Sridhar, thank you. Your link was helpful. I read the explanation and followed the advice on the associated page http://trustdarkness.com/wordpress/dell-sputnik-xps-13-touchpad-settings-not-working-in-updated-ubuntumint/  This seems to have solved the touchpad problem. After 10 reboots, it worked each time and the dmseg errors are gone. However, it seems to have caused a new problem. Now the computer immediately resumes from suspend--it will not stay suspended--something it was not doing before the fix. Should I start a new thread or continue here since it may be related to the previous fix?

Comment: Great! Better start a new thread regarding that issue@user3221829

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1296743),

Do the Following:

1. Open **`/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`** in your favorite text editor.
2. Add the line ***`blacklist i2c-hid`***
3. Save and reboot