# Prevent Immediate Resume after Suspend

Tags: 14.04, kernel, dell, suspend, resume

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell I7352-3111SLV 13 inch touchscreen.

As per [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661985/touchpad-only-works-after-hibernate/662767?noredirect=1#comment955850_662767) I've fixed my touchpad, But my machine now resumes from suspend as soon as it finishes the power down cycle. So, I followed various post but still I can't to fix it?

The things that I've followed:

> Running sudo pm-suspend
>
> Running sudo pm-suspend
>
> Running sudo pm-suspend --quirk-radeon-off.

And by Unplugging the mouse and running suspend.

Other attempted fixes:

As per [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148481/how-do-i-prevent-immediate-wake-up-from-suspend-and-or-hibernation) post,
I attempted to edit `/proc/acpi/wakeup` hence I've disabled all the three and I [Pasted here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12121981/)
But, Same immediate resume.

Additionally, I've tried both of the scripts provided by
[DragonNinja9](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978290) But still,no change.

Below I've Pasted some logs which might be useful to troubleshoot:

[pm-suspend.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12121977/)

[kern.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12121975/)

Comment: Kindly paste those commands to this http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and make it brief

Comment: Sridhar, thanks for pointing out the Pastebin. I have used it to shorten the post.