# HP Elitebook 1050 G1 - Clickpad only works after wakeup ubuntu18.04

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, hp

I recently installed `ubuntu 18.04` on the `HP Elitebook 1050 G1` and am running into issues with the clickpad.

When my machine first starts the clickpad doesn't work but if I put it to sleep, and wake it up it works fine.

I've seen other users run into this issue and have tried adding the following line to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.nomux=1 locale=fr_FR i8042.reset"
```

I tried reloading the following modules without success:

- psmouse
- rmi_smbus
- i2c_hid

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does double tapping upper left hand touchpad corner with your forefinger reactivate it?

Comment: Would be interesting to see/compare dmesg before and after a suspend

Comment: Does this trick solve your issue? https://askubuntu.com/questions/661985/touchpad-only-works-after-hibernate

Comment: @meda if you have the same problem: can you edit the question and post the output of `synclient` ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same laptop and here is my experience:

You need to have **psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=0** in grub settings or else touchpad behaves like a slowly broken mouse and ubuntu 18.04 doesn't recognize it as a touchpad but a regular mouse.

1. Kernel 4.18: First boot will not have a touchpad. Suspend once to get touchpad back but lose keyboard. Suspend one more time to get both keyboard and touchpad.
2. Kernel 4.19/.20: First boot will have both touchpad and keyboard. However, after Suspend, touchpad becomes erratic and CPU for touchpad IRQ/snaptic constantly use 7% CPU draining battery and cause CPU to unable to sleep.

So 4.19/20 fixed boot issue but the CPU usage of touchpad IRQ after Suspend is killing me.

Comment: I haven't tried Kernel 4.19/20 but I switched to Fedora and it works great with both 28/29 Haven't noticed any CPU draining but ill key an eye out for it. Have you had any audio issues when plugging in headphones? I recall it playing from the rear speakers while headphones plugged in :o